# Spring Boot & Mustache formatting date

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, date

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot application but I'm having a trouble that I cannot fix properly. I'm using JPA repositories to use SQL Database and I wanna save the birth date of users, but I don't know how to format dates (like dd/MM/yyyy) when showing them via Mustache templating.

This is my code:

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class User{
...
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date birthDate;
...
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController(){
    @GetMapping("/admin/user/list")
    public String userList(Model model){
        List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("userList", userList);
        return "/admin/user/list";
    }
...
}
```

View:

```
<html>
...
<strong>Fecha de nacimiento:</strong> {{ formatBirthDate }}<br>
...
</html>
```

Thanks to everyone for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Spring Boot** uses **JMustache** as templating engine for mustache files. By default, **JMustache** uses `String.valueOf` to convert objects to strings when rendering a template.

Therefore the annotation is ignored and dates are just converted to:

```java
jshell> String.valueOf(new java.util.Date())
$2 ==> "Tue Mar 09 23:29:23 CET 2021"
```

There are a few solutions with having its own tradeoffs:

- Map the `User` instances to a `UserViewModel` having a properly formatted birthDate as `String` and return those instead of your JPA entity
- Add a user defined object formatter by registering your own `MustacheViewResolver` or `Mustache.Compiler` see those links for reference:

  - https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache#user-defined-object-formatting
  - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mustache/MustacheAutoConfiguration.java

```
Mustache.compiler().withFormatter(new Mustache.Formatter() {
    public String format (Object value) {
      if (value instanceof Date) return _fmt.format((Date)value);
      else return String.valueOf(value);
    }
    protected DateFormat _fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
});
```

You can find a working example here:
https://github.com/AndreasKl/stackoverflow66555533